# Playing audio directly from a python program (text to speech)

Tags: audio, python-3.6, text-to-speech

I am trying to figure out how to play audio from a python program without needing to have the audio saved to my computer. The sound is created in the python program and just needs to be played and stopped immediately after.

I have already tried to use pygame, playsound, subprocess, gTTS and various others, but with no success.

gTTS "works" but only saves the audio and does not play it

Also I am using python 3 (I updated on 6/18/18)

PyAudio attempt did not work for me. But here is my code:

```
import subprocess 
from gtts import gTTS 
if choose in card.keys(): 
  tts = gTTS(text = choose, lang = 'en') 
  tts.save(audio_eng) 
  checker(guess, choose, card, pract_one, good_count, bad_count, pract_two) 
  return_code = subprocess.call(["afplay", audio_eng])#, shell= True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main library used for this kind of thing is [PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/). It's built ontop of portaudio (a C library), which I have used many times.

If you have generated the audio in Python, then you can simply pass it to the output similar to the example on the PyAudio documentation ([Blocking mode Audio I/O](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-blocking-mode-audio-i-o)). This will stop other processes happening until the audio file has finished playing.

```
"""PyAudio Example: Play a wave file."""

import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024


# wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') # Original example
wf = your_audio_data_array

# instantiate PyAudio (1)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# open stream (2)
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(your_audio_data_samplewidth),
                channels=your_audio_data_nChannels,
                rate=your_audio_data_framerate,
                output=True)

# read data
data = wf # your_audio_data_array

# play stream (3)
while len(data) > 0:
    stream.write(data)
    # data = wf.readframes(CHUNK) # read more data if you want to stream another buffer

# stop stream (4)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

# close PyAudio (5)
p.terminate()
```

I have modified this example to how you explained your problem was; so you just pass PyAudio the audio data buffer (which you said you already generated in Python).

To have multiple processes happening at once, see the [PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) Callback Mode I/O in [their documentation](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-callback-mode-audio-i-o).